# Accept zipped filetypes in HTML input field

Tags: html

I have the following line in my HTML:

```
<input type="file" nv-file-select multiple="" uploader="uploader" accept=".vcf, .vcf.gz"/>
```

When submitting a file through this, it only allows files that are '.vcf', not the gzipped ones. Can't find anything online pertaining to this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try just ".gz" instead of ".vcf.gz" and then do additional work in the javascript to verify ".vcf.gz"